# Sorting through a Json list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I have a JSON list that has been parsed without the use of JSON.parse and any online tutorial or other forum doesn't work for this task.
The code:

```
var result = '{{ bans }}';

  var parser = new DOMParser;
  var dom = parser.parseFromString(
    '<!doctype html><body>' + result,
    'text/html');
  var res = dom.body.textContent;

  console.log(res)

for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; ++i) {
};
```

If you want to know why its parsed like this check out my last post. The above code doesn't work for looping through it, I also need to get the info such as username from the ban. The JSON

```
{
  "bans": [
    {
      "appealable": false, 
      "banend": "Fri, 15 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "bannedby": "parker02311", 
      "banstart": "Fri, 15 Jan 2021 00:18:58 GMT", 
      "id": 1, 
      "images": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/642127559600898058/799867505727504464/Roblox_1_15_2021_11_07_09_PM_2.png,https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/642127559600898058/799863972915314688/Roblox_1_15_2021_10_53_30_PM_2.png", 
      "notes": "<p>test</p>", 
      "reasons": "Chat Bypassing, Discrimination", 
      "userid": "17", 
      "username": "test"
    }, 
    {
      "appealable": false, 
      "banend": "Wed, 20 Jan 2021 00:00:00 GMT", 
      "bannedby": "parker02311", 
      "banstart": "Sat, 16 Jan 2021 05:46:33 GMT", 
      "id": 2, 
      "images": "https://image.prntscr.com/image/DUQMlOEKTuGDHSkvB4NuRQ.png,https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/642127559600898058/799874004457488394/unknown.png", 
      "notes": "", 
      "reasons": "Chat Bypassing,Discrimination", 
      "userid": "202181894", 
      "username": "Dagdoubleagaming"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using your `res` variable as a JSON string, since that's effectively what that would be now that you've removed the HTML encoding (as per your last post).

```
var res = dom.body.innerHTML;
var JSONObj = JSON.parse(res);
```

And then you should be able to use JSONObj as a normal object

Comment: Just errors `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Then the only solution I am seeing for you is to write your own JSON parser, unless you can figure out how to somehow make your original JSON variable into an acceptable type?

Comment: What do you mean by acceptable type? Its all JSON, the result was jsonified in Flask, it should be an acceptable type...

Comment: If it were proper JSON then JSON.parse would work, is there any way you can change the backend to send it as application/json instead of text/html?

Comment: It should be application/json like its returning a https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=jsonify#flask.json.jsonify

Comment: Jesus, I love coding I SOLVED THIS ERROR BUT NOW I HAVE ANOTHER ONE :face_palm:

Comment: What was this issue?

Comment: It was weird for the way I fixed it but instead of parse, I had to do .json